# Android Studio : Cursor changing itself to overwrite mode

Tags: android-studio, ide, android-cursor

My cursor in android studio(chipmunk) is changing itself from writing mode to overwrite mode whenever I select texts. And my ctrl + C and ctrl + V is also not working, I haven't changed any settings up to my knowledge.

[1][This picture depicts the cursor in write mode]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ph1k.png
```

[2][This picture depicts the cursor changing into overwrite mode itself after I select some texts]

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0s61.png
```

Can anyone help me  out solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove vim plugin in android studio and then restart android studio

Answer (score 1):

press insert and fn keys together.

Comment: Please elaborate, add more explanation of what this does and why it helps. Consider taking the [tour] and reading [answer].

Comment: What about on MacBook Air with no insert key?